# Mulitple websites with one instance or with multiple?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, multi-website, multidomain

I'm not familiar with Magento 2, but would like to know how to deal with multiple shops. I read that Magento supports multiple websites, what sounds interesting. However, I'm wondering when that could or should be used. What are the pros and cons regarding one Magento instance with multiple sites vs one instance per site. When should be used what?

- Is the multi website feature of Magento only useful if the shops have
  something in common?
- If one shop deals with tools and another with shoes, is one instance applicable?
- How about running 100 shops?
- How about backend users? One admin, multiple managers (one per shop).
- Would you recommend the commerce edition or can all be done with the community edition likewise?
- What is the main intention to have the multi website feature?

Answer (score 1):

**Is the multi website feature of Magento only useful if the shops have something in common?** No, they can used for multiple scenarios. Usually multiple store views are used for different languages or scenarios where the products offering is similar and multi website is used for different production offerings.

**If one shop deals with tools and another with shoes, is one instance applicable?** Yes, you could use multi websites and keep them separated that way.

**How about running 100 shops?** I don't believe there is a limit on the number of shops you can have on a single instance. However, managing that many would be a serious undertaking.

**How about backend users? One admin, multiple managers (one per shop).** You can set up different user groups so certain people have access to certain stores.

**Would you recommend the commerce edition or can all be done with the community edition likewise?** Both should work, but selecting the version should depend more on the feature's you need/want.

**What is the main intention to have the multi website feature?** It allows for the separation of data, reporting, and data management. You can also have completely different storefront frontend appearance giving the impression that you have completely different sites while still managing everything from a single backend.

Comment: When would it be recommended to have not a single Magento instance?

Comment: @robsch it really depends on your specific use case or business requirements but I would think it would better to have multiple if you’re dealing with different business entities.

Comment: I know, it always depends ... :-D ... But I think there are some general recommendations possible. I also guess, if there is nothing that can be shared in any way, it makes less sense to have a single instance. It might be more secure to have several.